# How to setup db connection between AWS EC2 hosted spring boot app and AWS key space?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-keyspaces

Here I am trying to connect my AWS ec2 hosted spring boot application to AWS keyspace.
Is there anything specific configuration that needs to be done?

I am following this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/using_java_driver.html#java_tutorial.SigV4

Answer (score 1):

That's a good place to start with. For driver policies, examples, and best practices when using the Java Driver with Amazon Keyspaces [amazon-keyspaces-java-driver-helpers](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-keyspaces-java-driver-helpers)

you can also refer to [keyspaces aws samples](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-keyspaces-examples) for examples on connecting to Amazon Keyspaces via Lambda etc

On how to compress your data using freely available compression tools and store that [compressed data in Amazon Keyspaces](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-keyspaces-compression-example)